# Array paased to a function with const parameter

Tags: c

What happen when I try to modify the contents of an array that is passed to a function that receives the arrays as a const parameter

Comment: Er... compilation error? What do you expect?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: The compiler will recognize it as error. But even, if you make some cast (to non-const) tricks the program may (or may not) crash at runtime. I observed this a few weeks ago with gcc in cygwin (Windows 10) where I tried to change a constant C string (out of curiosity). It seems that gcc puts constant data into a special segment where write access is forbidden. Other compilers might be more generous. Other platforms (than Intel PC) may lack the necessary protection features and allow this. The best way is to prevent such hacking techniques...

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in fact `const` you invoke **undefined behaviour**.

```
#include <stddef.h>

void zlast(const int *s, size_t len) {
    int *ss = (int *)s; /* remove const'ness; silence warning */
    ss[len - 1] = 0; /* possible UB */
}

int main(void) {
    const int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int y[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42};
    zlast(y, sizeof y / sizeof *y); /* ok */
    zlast(x, sizeof x / sizeof *x); /* UB */
    return 0;
}
```